# Laravel array key validation

Tags: laravel, validation

I have custom request data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "checkThisKeyForExists": [
            {
                "value": "Array key Validation"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And this validation rules:

```
$rules = [
    'data' => ['required','array'],
    'data.*' => ['exists:table,id']
];
```

How I can validate array key using Laravel?

Comment: Use Nested dot operator like data.*.value required something like this

Comment: I have custom array with **defined keys** for example `$keys = ['foo', 'bar']` and I must check request array key for exist with my defined keys. Array keys can't be instead of defined keys. @SagarGautam

Answer (score 3):

**The right way**
This isn't possible in Laravel out of the box, but you can add a new validation rule to validate array keys:

```sh
php artisan make:rule KeysIn
```

The rule should look roughly like the following:

```php
class KeysIn implements Rule
{
    public function __construct(protected array $values)
    {
    }

    public function message(): string
    {
        return ':attribute contains invalid fields';
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value): bool
    {
        // Swap keys with their values in our field list, so we
        // get ['foo' => 0, 'bar' => 1] instead of ['foo', 'bar']
        $allowedKeys = array_flip($this->values);

        // Compare the value's array *keys* with the flipped fields
        $unknownKeys = array_diff_key($value, $allowedKeys);

        // The validation only passes if there are no unknown keys
        return count($unknownKeys) === 0;
    }
}
```

You can use this rule like so:

```php
$rules = [
    'data' => ['required','array', new KeysIn(['foo', 'bar'])],
    'data.*' => ['exists:table,id']
];
```

**The quick way**
If you only need to do this once, you can do it the quick-and-dirty way, too:

```php
$rules = [
    'data' => [
        'required',
        'array',
        fn(attribute, $value, $fail) => count(array_diff_key($value, $array_flip([
            'foo',
            'bar'
        ]))) > 0 ? $fail("{$attribute} contains invalid fields") : null
    ],
    'data.*' => ['exists:table,id']
];
```

Comment: on my use case, some array keys can be optional this won't work

Answer (score 3):

maybe it will helpful for you

```
$rules = ([
        'name' => 'required|string',              //your field
        'children.*.name' => 'required|string',           //your 1st nested field
        'children.*.children.*.name => 'required|string'        //your 2nd nested field
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking:

```
$rules = [
   'data.checkThisKeyForExists.value' => ['exists:table,id']
];
```

Comment: Array keys will be not static and I must compare given keys with my defined keys. If given key from request exist in defined array keys then return `true` else `false` @Sallmin Rexha

Comment: I must check for exist array key instead of array value @Sallmin Rexha

Comment: I don't know if you can do that.